# Навигация каретки в Text Formatter API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, редактор-текста

Используя [Text Formatter API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ms754036(v=vs.100).aspx) в WPF для проектирования простого текстового редактора, понадобилось добавить управление кареткой. В документации нашёл в описании класса [TextLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textline(v=vs.110).aspx) методы `GetNextCaretCharacterHit`, `GetPreviousCaretCharacterHit` и `GetBackspaceCaretCharacterHit`. Но только вот все 3 метода - абстрактные. Примеров их реализации толком и не нашёл (разве что пару в исходниках .NET).

Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить/привести пример, что представляет из себя рабочая реализация этих методов и как они работают? Или же работу с кареткой можно реализовать другим способом? Буду рад любой помощи!

> P.S.: Ранее я задал [такой же вопрос на основном Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32423263/4937047), но там он уже затерялся. Так что если считаете этот вопрос полезным и голосуете за него здесь, то, пожалуйста, проголосуйте и там, если не сложно, ибо так вероятность, что на вопрос ответят, будет больше. Надеюсь, моя просьба не является некорректной.

**UPD:**

**Кратко о решаемой задаче:**
Мне нужно добавить обычную навигацию каретки по тексту, т.е. управление ею клавишами перемещения курсора, её смещение при удалении и вводе текста (последние два пункта кое-как реализовал через методы `GetCharacterHitFromDistance` и `GetDistanceFromCharacterHit`, правда всё это как-то кривовато получилось, т.к. в случае смещения каретки при вводе текста я непосредственно создаю экземпляр CharacterHit, указывая в конструкторе вторым аргументом (который представляет trailingLength - что это, см. ниже) единицу:
`CharacterHit chHit = new CharacterHit(CurrentPosition, 1);` (`CurrentPosition` здесь просто свойство типа int.

> *Что такое `trailingLength` в данном случае?* В документации о `trailingLength` сказано: "В случае переднего края значение равно 0. В случае заднего края это значение равно количеству кодовых точек до следующей допустимой позиции курсора. " Почитав о том, что такое кодовые точки и о Юникоде в целом, всё становится понятно: большинство часто используемых символов состоят из одной кодовой точки. Пример составных - комбинирование символов с диакретическими знаками, например: \u0418\u0306 = Й в Юникоде (хотя \u0419 = Й также).

К слову, я так и не разобрался, как обеспечить корректную работу каретки (то бишь с использованием тех встроенных методов `Get*CaretCharacterHit`). Я пробовал хранить текущую позицию не как int-значение, а как `CharacterHit`, чтобы пользоваться теми методами (все они принимают текущий `CharacterHit` и возвращают новый). Но в итоге всё практически перестало адекватно работать.

Comment: Можно подробнее узнать о задаче? Скорее всего вам не нужны эти абстрактные методы.

Comment: @iRumba, Да без проблем. Мне нужно добавить обычную навигацию каретки по тексту, т.е. управление ею клавишами перемещения курсора, её смещение при удалении и вводе текста (последние два пункта кое-как реализовал через методы `GetCharacterHitFromDistance` и `GetDistanceFromCharacterHit`, правда всё это как-то кривовато получилось, т.к. в случае смещения каретки при вводе текста я непосредственно создаю экземпляр CharacterHit, указывая в конструкторе вторым аргументом (который представляет trailingLength - что это, я не до конца понимаю; реальная длина представления символа в Юникоде?) единицу.

Comment: В этом случае возникают проблемы с символом новой строки. Ну и перемещение каретки в в ближайшую к точке нажатия позицию в тексте, что я уже сделал с помощью метода `GetCharacterHitFromDistance`. В общем, всё что обычно имеется во всех текстовых редакторах.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, trailingLength - это начальное положение, а не ширина символа. То есть равно положению каретки для ввода символа. Для проверки, так ли это, получите значения TheCharacterHit.TrailingLength для разных экземпляров CharacterHit в тексте.

Comment: А какие значения firstCharacterIndex вы передаете в конструктор CharacterHit?

Comment: @iRumba, число, указывающее текущую позицию в тексте.
Как я заметил, если рассматривать обычные символы (которые, по крайней мере, входят в ASCII), то для них значение `TrailingLength` равны либо 0 (когда я нажимаю на левую часть символа), либо 1 (когда нажимаю на правую часть символа).

Comment: Разберите строку и выведите TheCharacterHit.TrailingLength и TheCharacterHit.FirstCharacterIndex для каждого символа строки. Уверен, это прояснит положение вещей. И поможет мне помочь вам разобраться :)

Comment: Странно, что это значение меняется в зависимости от положения курсора по отношению к символу. Вы щелкали по разным символам в строке? Сколько их? Скорее всего вы просто щелкаете по одному (первому) символу и получаете значение 0, потому что ближайший CharacterHit - предыдущий, а 1, потому что следующий. Пощелкайте по символам по всей строке. А у меня рабочий день окончен, завтра продолжим тесты. Просьба дописывать результаты ваших изысканий, чтобы завтра я не задавал лишних вопросов. :)

Comment: @iRumba, я именно по всем символам и проверял. Везде одно и то же. Я всё же склонен думать, что `TrailingLength` - это длина кода символа в Юникоде. Но вот точно не уверен, ведь для часто используемых символов, типа букв латиницы, кириллицы, цифр и т.п. `TrailingLength` = 1. Как я заметил, `CharacterHit.FirstCharacterIndex` возвращает как раз то значение, где и должна находиться каретка. Так что пока кое-как работает. Только вот каретка игнорирует ввод символа новой строки. Думаю, это из-за того, что `TextFormatter` не включает его в `TextLine`.

Comment: @iRumba, точнее, не игнорирует, а на этом участке кода:
`caret.Left = currTextLine.TextLine.GetDistanceFromCharacterHit(chHit);`
выбрасывается исключение, т.к. `currTextLine == null`. Это происходит потому, currTextLine не получает значения здесь:
`VisualTextLine currTextLine = textLines.Find(x => x.ContainsIndex(CurrentPosition));`, где `VisualTextLine` - мой класс, имеющий свойство типа `TextLine` и также хранящий информацию о координате этой `TextLine`; метод `ContainsIndex` проверяет принадлежность переданного индекса диапазону размеров данного `TextLine`;

Comment: @iRumba, а textLines - это `List<VisualTextLine>`, который наполняется после прорисовки каждой линии. Т.е., по сути, в этом списке хранятся только TextLine'ы. Так что найти индекс символа новой строки не удаётся, видимо, потому, что он просто не включается в TextLine (что логично - его ведь не надо прорисовывать - это ведь просто индикатор того, что дальнейший текст нужно начинать с новой строки).

Поэтому я пока не знаю, как перемещать каретку на новую строку при его появлении.

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю... Методы `GetCharacterHitFromDistance` и `GetDistanceFromCharacterHit` также абстрактные и не имеют реализации (судя по исходникам .NET)... Как они в таком случае работают? Как-то я немного озадачен...

Comment: @iRumba, возвращаясь к теме TrailingLength, хочу сказать, что я разобрался. Всему виной моё незнание сути Юникода. В документации о trailingLength сказано: "_В случае переднего края значение равно 0. В случае заднего края это значение равно количеству кодовых точек до следующей допустимой позиции курсора._ " Почитав о том, что такое _кодовые точки_ и о Юникоде в целом, всё стало на свои места: большинство часто используемых символов состоят из одной кодовой точки. Пример составных - комбинирование символов с диакретическими знаками, например: \u0418\u0306 = Й в Юникоде (хотя \u0419 = Й также).

Comment: Что такое CurrentPosition? Как устроена функция ContainsIndex? Вы очень странно ее описали и я не понимаю ее предназначения, отправьте ее код. Почему VisualTextLine содержит свойство типа TextLine, а не наследует класс?

Comment: Прочитал причину, по которой не используете RichTextBox. я так понимаю, это курсовая или диплом? Я бы на вашем месте уточнил, можно ли использовать RichTextBox, потому что он не является готовым решением, это просто расширенный инструмент, а не готовая программа. Он умеет копать, умеет летать, умеет говорить. Но где копать, куда лететь и что сказать, уже указываете вы сами )

Comment: @iRumba, `CurrentPosition` - просто свойство типа int. `ContainsIndex` устроена очень просто. В `VisualTextLine` хранится точка левого верхнего угла объекта `TextLine` (`startIndex`), а сама `TextLine` имеет свойство `Length`. Указанная выше функция делает следующее: ` return index >= startIndex && index < startIndex + TextLine.Length` , где `index` - параметр функции.

Comment: @iRumba : "Почему VisualTextLine содержит свойство типа TextLine, а не наследует класс? " 
Да, можно было бы просто унаследовать класс, согласен. Проскочил этот момент. Но пока на работе это никак не сказывается. Так что, думаю, это несущественный момент.

Comment: @iRumba, нет, не диплом и не курсовая. Просто всего-навсего лабораторная. Из большего всё сделано (криво, конечно, но условия задания почти выполняет, так что лучше уже доведу  до конца, а позже буду подправлять). Осталось только исправить этот момент с переводом каретки на новую строку и прикрутить выделение и редактирование фрагментов текста. Что же касается `RichTextBox`: его применять однозначно запретили.

Comment: Если бы вы наследовали класс, вас бы заставили переопределить все методы))  Так как это всего лишь свойство, которое вы, к тому же, не можете создать сами, потому что конструктор от вас скрыт, вы создаете его иными способами. Посему я не удивлен, что абстрактные свойства у вас работают. Раз `TextFormatter` вам его создает, он же его и перегружает. То есть в возвращаемый объект типа TextLine на самом деле уже завернут объект переопределенного типа. Скорее всего вам не нужно ничего делать самостоятельно.

Comment: @iRumba, да, точно, наконец-то до меня дошло. метод `TextFormatter.FormatLine` возвращает объект типа `TextLine`, а в исходниках .NET определены внутренние классы `SimpleTextLine` и `FullTextLine`, объекты которых по факту и возвращает выше упомянутый метод.

Comment: @iRumba, а `VisualTextLine` нужен лишь для того, чтобы сохранять данные о позиции TextLine и делать проверку попадания нажатия, а также индекса. В самом `TextLine` нету соответствующих членов.

Comment: Не совсем корректный подход. Данные о позиции, например, должны возвращаться классом, который хранит в себе коллекцию TextLine, но не оберткой над этим классом. Данные о нажатии в этом классе и вовсе не нужны. Вы же щелкаете по области, в которой расположены эти TextLine, от нее и пляшите. В общем то что вы назвали, должны решать коллекции и контейнер.

Comment: @iRumba, просто обёртка - это первое, что пришло мне на ум. Да и реализуется это очень просто. А мне нужно было для начала просто добиться работающего функционала, ибо я не был уверен в успехе. К слову, я так и не разобрался, как обеспечить корректную работу каретки (то бишь с использованием тех встроенных методов `Get*CaretCharacterHit`). Я пробовал хранить текущую позицию не как int-значение, а как `CharacterHit`, чтобы пользоваться теми методами (все они принимают текущий `CharacterHit` и возвращают новый). Но в итоге всё практически перестало адекватно работать.

Comment: @Dark_Clark Перенесите все ваши дополнения из комментариев в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> методы GetNextCaretCharacterHit, GetPreviousCaretCharacterHit
>     и GetBackspaceCaretCharacterHit
>   Может ли кто-нибудь объяснить/привести пример, что представляет 
>     из себя рабочая реализация этих методов и как они работают?

реализация [GetPreviousCaretCharacterHit](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/MS/Internal/TextFormatting/SimpleTextLine.cs,746).
 
остальные реализации можно найти там же, на http://referencesource.microsoft.com